# Entity Framework CTP5 (Code First) Modeling - lookup tables

Tags: entity-framework, data-modeling, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

Assume the following table structure:

**Tables:**

```
**Tasks**
taskID int PK
taskName varchar

**Resources**
resourceID int PK
resourceName varchar

**Assignments**
assignmentID int PK
taskID int FK
resourceID int FK
```

The assignments table relates a task with the resource that is assigned to it. Is it possible to map this structure with the model builder so that I do not have to create an Assignment poco class - hiding some of the underlying data structure?

I.E.:

```
public class Task
{
    public int taskID { get; set; }
    public string taskName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Resource> resourceItems { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public int resourceID { get; set; }
    public string resourceName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use the model builder to map tasks to resources without creating an assignment poco class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is an article about this very thing](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/inserting-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-with-or-without-a-join-entity/).

Edit, I dont have an IDE in front of me so this might not be the exact "latest" syntax, but it should get you started:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasMany(a => a.Resources).WithMany(b => b.Tasks).Map(m => 
{ 

  m.MapLeftKey(a => a.TaskId,"taskId");

  m.MapRightKey(b => b.ResourceId, "resourceId");

  m.ToTable("Assignments"); 

});
```

Comment: In that article EF is doing that in the ssdl & csdl. I need to know how to map it in code using the model builder. I may have no been clear in my question that I'm using the code-first approach in CTP5. I've updated my title.